# FB.UI apprequests inside a frame causes script access denied error

Tags: facebook, authentication

I am working on an application, which is iframed into another application (different domain). My application which is in the iframe has apprequest functionality implemented. For some reason, whenever I invoke the apprequest dialog, I get a script access denied error.

The following are all the details:

App A --> is in domainA
App B --> is in domainB and is Iframed in to App A.

App B has a button which invokes, the following code:

```
FB.login(function (resp) {
   FB.ui({
      method: 'apprequests',
      message: msg,
      display: 'iframe',
      access_token: resp.authResponse.accessToken
   }, fbRequestCallback);
});
```

This throws an error. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

If a user clicks 'Accept' on a Request, they will be sent to the Canvas Page URL of the app that sent the Request. So the request will always be sent back to App that generated the request. You will then have to read the request at:

https://apps.facebook.com/[app_name]/?request_ids=[request_ids]

and redirect it accordingly.

Comment: The access denied error is happening way before I send the apprequest, not when the user clicked the accept button. It is occuring when I try to send the request.